# INSERT INTO command in SQLite with C++ doesnt work

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a problem with an INSERT INTO command using SQLite3 in C++.

I want to save different strings in an existing database.
I already tested it with static values. There it works fine.
But when I want to save generated strings in that database, the database is empty every time.

Thats my c++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "createdb.h"

using namespace std;

/* Converts Strings into quotes */
string quotesql( const string& s ) {
return string("'") + s + string("'");
}


double addquery(string name, string email,  double temp, double humidy, double intervall)
{
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg = 0;
int rc;
char *sql_insert;

double i = 1;

/* Convert Double into String */
stringstream NumberString;

NumberString << temp;
string stringtemp = NumberString.str();

NumberString << humidy;
string stringhumidy = NumberString.str();

NumberString << intervall;
string stringintervall = NumberString.str();

NumberString << i;
string stringi = NumberString.str();

string stringname = name;
string stringemail = email;



/* Open database */
rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
if( rc ){
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  exit(0);
}else{
  fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
}

/* This INSERT INTO command works fine
sql_insert = "INSERT INTO einstellungen (ID,EMAIL,NAME,TEMP,INTERVALL,HUMIDY)" \
     "VALUES (1, 'user@test.com', 'John Doe', -5, 50, 20 );"; */
/*

/* This INSERT INTO command doesn't work */
string sqlstatement =
"INSERT INTO einstellungen (ID, EMAIL, NAME, TEMP, INTERVALL, HUMIDY) VALUES ("
+ quotesql(stringi) + ","
+ quotesql(stringemail) + ","
+ quotesql(stringname) + ","
+ quotesql(stringtemp) + ","
+ quotesql(stringintervall) + ","
+ quotesql(stringhumidy) + ");";

*/




/* Execute SQL statement */
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql_insert, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
  fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
  sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}else{
  fprintf(stdout, "Einstellungen gespeichert\n");
}
sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;
}
```

Does anybody know where I make a mistake?

Thanks a lot :-)

I create some cout commands after each string command.
Here is the result:

I build some cout commands between each string command:

Here the result:

```
Datenbank wird nun angelegt
Datenbank erfolgreich angelegt
Datenbank erfolgreich initalisiert
Stringtemp: -5
Strinhumidy: 25
Stringintervall: 500
Stringi: 1
Stringname: John Doe
Stringemail: john.doe@online.de
Opened database successfully
INSERT INTO einstellungen (ID,EMAIL,NAME,TEMP,INTERVALL,HUMIDY)VALUES 
(1,'john.doe@online.de','John Doe',-5,500,25);
Einstellungen gespeichert
```

Comment: Print out the SQL before executing it, and edit your post with that info if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your numerical values such as `stringhumidy` shouldn't be enclosed in quotes. If you still have a problem then print somewhere the value of the `sqlstatement` in order to find what the error is.

Comment: I print out the sqlstatement.
See in the edited post

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake!

I added the following line:

```
char * buffer = new char[sqlstatement.length()];
strcpy(buffer,sqlstatement.c_str());
```

So i converted the sqlstatement (string) into the required char operator